# How to add default option to plucked array in laravel

Tags: laravel-8

I want to add default option at the start of a plucked array in Laravel 8. How can I achieve this?

```
$departments = Department::pluck('name', 'id')->all();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
prepend()

$departments = Department::pluck('name', 'id')->prepend('Select Department', '');
```